# What is the name, meaning and function of the circle(s) in this composition of functions?

Tags: characters

This is the S-DES encryption algorithm. I don't recognize this character.

Sidebar: How can I write this in LaTeX/MathJax?

[image: S-DES]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circles are usually read "of", and they refer to [function composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition).

For two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$:
$(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$

So $\text{IP}^{-1} \circ f_{K_2} \circ \text{SW} \circ f_{K_1} \circ \text{IP} = \text{IP}^{-1} ( f_{K_2} ( \text{SW} ( f_{K_1} ( \text{IP}))))$.

Answer (score 2):

It's a `circle`, denoted by `\circ`. For example,

$$f \circ g \circ h.$$

And then your given example looks like

$$\rm IP^{-1} \circ f_{K_2} \circ SW \circ f_{K_1} \circ IP.$$

And in the future, you should check out [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) for your symbol-finding needs (and/or google).

Comment: Thanks! Google is generally my first option, but I didn't know how to phrase this without an example. Also, this link is awesome!